# google search result shows html and angularJs code

Tags: meta-tags, google-search

I have created a web site. 
the Google search result is showing some extra code which is part of html and angular js.

i have added the folowing metatags but no use

```
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="robots" content="nosnippnet">
<meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP, nofollow, nosnippnet">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
```

I have waited for 3 weeks so that google will reindex. but no use. can any one tell me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You've got spelling mistake..

change nosnippnet to nosnippet